# json data is not display until resize browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, json

I have JSON data of category and products it is perfectly getting in alert or console.

But when I am passing it in to TreeView it is not displaying until <kbd>resize browser window</kbd>.

After Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>resize browser window</kbd> it is working perfectly after  .

[image]

Here as above in before <kbd>F12</kbd> and below after pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>

[image]

Do You have any idea?

Comment: Could it be due to window resize? Instead of pressing F12, test by resizing the window and see if same behaviour

Comment: yes I think you are right after resizing window it is showing but how can I overcome it?

Comment: I guess there is a resize handler somewhere. You could try if its a jquery resize handler to trigger it once the treeView is initialized: `$(window).trigger('resize')` Or check in your console for any handler bound to element: `$._data($('#mytreeview')[0],'events')` But in order to get more accurate help, we need to know relevant code

Comment: Hi I tried jQuery('#id').trigger('resize'); but its not working. any  other solution for that.

Comment: I cannot debug code just by seeing pictures... You need to provide relevant code... If you don't know which code to provide, then you have to debug it on your side